# Quotient over modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Suppose $a$ is divisible by $b$, and their quotient $(\frac ab)$ is $k$. Does it hold that for any prime number $p$, $ k \bmod p= (a \bmod p * (b^{-1})\bmod p) \mod p$?
Note that $b^{-1}$ is the modular inverse of $b$ with respect to $p$. 
I am aware this statement does not hold for the quotient of $a$ by $b$ when $a \bmod b$ is not $0$. But in the case where $b$ does divide $a$, is this expansion valid?

Comment: Please use MathJax to make your question more readable. Replace `mod` by `\bmod`, put `$` signs around everything, replace `^-1` by `^{-1}`, `a/b` by `\frac ab`.

Comment: Could you point me to documentation for the math format please?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: In fact since you introduce $k$, I'd also replace $\left(\frac ab\right)$ by $k$ here. But good job on the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

If $a=bk$ in $\Bbb Z$, then $a=bk$ in $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$.

If furthermore $b$ is invertible then you can multiply both sides by $b^{-1}$ to get $$ab^{-1}=k$$ in $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$